# Disable redirect notice in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I regularly click on links in calendar events for work and *every single time* Google Calendar first sends me to this page:

[image]

Since when is the default response to a user clicking on a link, "Let's send them first to an Are-You-Sure page"? It's just a link, for heaven's sake, not a prompt to download a 100GB file.

Not once have I "not wanted to" visit the page of the link I'm clicking on, and in Firefox this page even stays open after navigating to the final destination, so I have to go back and close the tab.

I find this *supremely* annoying. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable this via Google, that I can see, so you have to do this programatically. It looks like there are chrome extensions out there to do this for you, check out this as an example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skip-redirect/jaoafjdoijdconemdmodhbfpianehlon?hl=en.